# Locking down the browser to the max

Tags: security, spoofing

What extensions and settings must be added to the browser to make it as private and secure as possible? I know that the answer to this probably changes a lot as security changes. But so far what I have been able to think of is:

- Private mode
- With a Tor bridge
- Security level at safest
- HTTPS Everywhere
- NoScript
- Ublock or DDG Privacy essentials to amp up tracker blocking further
- Window not maximized
- User agent spoofer

What else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than changing the security level (or adding a bridge), you should not change any settings in Tor Browser.

> - With a Tor bridge

Bridges are useful for censorship-resistance, and don't do much in the way of privacy.

> - HTTPS Everywhere
> - NoScript

Tor Browser includes NoScript and HTTPS Everywhere.

> - Ublock or DDG Privacy essentials to amp up tracker blocking further
> - User agent spoofer

Other extensions (including these) will make you uniquely identifiable across sessions.

> - Window not maximized

Tor Browser include [letterboxing](https://support.torproject.org/tbb/maximized-torbrowser-window/), which means you can safely maximize your browser window.

Comment: Okay I think I understand, other than dialing up the security setting the true way to lock down the browser would be to make it as plain and bare as possible, letting you blend in

Comment: @CipherVisor Right, it's best to use an existing tool like Tor Browser, Tails, etc, and stick as close as you can to the default settings so that you look similar to other users.